# How to remove padding of QCheckBox in a QTreeWidget cell

Tags: qt, pyqt, padding, qtreewidget, qcheckbox

I've subclassed QWidget and used setItemWidget to set it as a cell widget. Here's the code for the subclass

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QHBoxLayout, QCheckBox, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt


class QFrozenWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        checkbox = QCheckBox()
        label = QLabel()
        label.setText("▲")
        layout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(checkbox)
        layout.addWidget(label)
```

This is how I set the widget to the cell, treeWidget_AddressTable was already declared in the ui file, it's normal QTreeWidget

```
current_row = QTreeWidgetItem()
frozen_widget = QFrozenWidget()
self.treeWidget_AddressTable.addTopLevelItem(current_row)
self.treeWidget_AddressTable.setItemWidget(current_row,FROZEN_COL,frozen_widget)
```

[image: qt misaligned checkbox]

Even with `Qt.AlignLeft` or `spacing` the checkbox has a gap between itself and the leftmost side of the freeze column. How do I remove it? I've subclassed QWidget as an attempt, I'm open to any kind of neat solution to this

Have a nice day people

Comment: That seems the space left to show the *decorations* of tree item, used to show and toggle the collapsed/expanded state of items and also the "lines" grouping items on the same level. That space is quite important, visually speaking.

Comment: There must be a configuration for this. Have you checked all the properties? E.g. I do not see you trying `setSpacing(0);` on your layout, just in case.

Comment: @KorcanKaraokçu Try with `self.treeWidget_AddressTable.setRootIsDecorated(False)`

Comment: `setRootIsDecorated` works properly, thanks for the answers. @musicamante was right, it's impossible to expand items without it. Laszlo, I've already tried spacing as I stated in the last paragraph, it doesn't work. It just wasn't represented in the last draft of the code

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, `setRootIsDecorated(False)` works but it also makes it impossible to expand items for the user. I've found out that the true answer to this was to use `setIndentation()` with the desired parameter. I'll be accepting this answer, thanks for the help